# Resident vs Non-resident alien in the United States

Tags: united-states, taxes, bank-account, savings-account, f1-student-visa

I have been in the United States since August 2015 in an F1 visa. I was away from January 2018 to May 2018 in Denmark for study abroad. I do have a SSN as well.

I wanted to open a savings account in Bank of America, but they ask me if I am a resident or non-resident alien. What should I put? If I select resident alien, they ask me for my SSN. But I am worried if it entails any problem in terms of taxes later.

Any help? I am sorry if this is not the right forum for this question. But my concern is eventually related to taxes.

Comment: your tax liabilities exist independently from opening an account.

Answer (score 1):

How you answer a bank's question shouldn't have any effect on how you are taxed.

However, assuming you haven't been in the US in F or J status before 2015, you are currently a nonresident alien for tax purposes. As a [student](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2017_publink1000222143), you are an "[exempt individual](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2017_publink1000222138)" (i.e. your days in the US in F1 status is not counted for the Substantial Presence Test) unless you have been an "exempt individual" for some part of 5 previous calendar years. So if you remain on F1, your days on F1 will only start counting (potentially making you a resident alien) in 2020, and not before then.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, answering questions truthfully is a good idea.  From what you wrote in your question, it seems that you are a resident alien under US laws.

A resident alien is a person with a green card or who meets the "[substantial presence test](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test)".  You seem to meet the latter, but you should confirm.